# Markup validation not showing green banner even though html file is error free

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my html file through https://validator.w3.org/
My file keeps getting redirected to Nu HTML checker but shows as "Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.I am wondering why I don't get the green banner and have my file fully validated like below.

[image]

Instead of this, this is what I get every time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://validator.w3.org/ is for older HTML versions,
https://validator.w3.org/nu/ is for HTML5 and later.

They are different tools. With the Nu Html Checker, they decided to switch the terminology from *validating* to *checking*.  [From the about page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html):

> The Nu Html Checker should not be used as a means to attempt to unilaterally enforce pass/fail conformance of documents to any particular specifications; it is intended solely as a checker, not as a pass/fail certification mechanism.

In other words, using the Nu Html Checker is helpful to find errors, but if it doesn’t find any errors (like in your screenshot, which by the way still does include a green banner), it doesn’t necessarily mean that your document is error-free/conformant.